# python: Indexes of an image from ndindex

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am iterating an image via the following code(i am beginner still in python):

```
for pixel in np.ndindex(imRGB.shape[:2]):
    print pixel
```

The shape of the image is: (900L, 1600L, 3L)

Is there a way while iterating to get the row and column of the pixel in addition to the RGB?

Comment: Here `pixel` is a tuple of the current 2 indices, `(0,0), (0,1)...`.  Those could be described as the (X,Y) of the pixel.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Look in the question, the array is 3D, pixel just give you the third dimension, i am interested in the first and second(row,column)

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach works fine! If you want to get the RGB value as well for that pixel location, you can try `imRGB[pixel]`. However, it is faster to just use two python loops to iterate over the axes. I have timed both methods as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import time

random_data = np.random.random_sample((900, 1600, 3))
imRGB = np.round(256 * random_data)

start = time.time()
for pixel in np.ndindex(imRGB.shape[:2]):
    x, y = pixel
    rgb = imRGB[pixel]
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

start = time.time()
for x in xrange(imRGB.shape[0]):
    for y in xrange(imRGB.shape[1]):
        x, y, imRGB[x, y]
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

The first method took 1.29 seconds on my laptop, while the second took 0.53 seconds. Depending on what you want to do within the loop, there could be other numpy-specific operations that could be faster that writing out loops. Hope this helps!